# .Net 6 runtime and windows updates

Tags: windows-update, .net-framework

I've written a WPF desktop application using Visual Studio 2022 and .Net SDK 6.0.6. I didn't want to create a "self-contained" application so it will be necessary to install the .Net Desktop Runtime on customer PCs. Am I right in saying that any version >=6.0.6 can be installed, and doesn't have to be specifically 6.0.6?

Also, the .Net6 runtime seems to be getting an updated every month. Does Windows Update include updates to .Net6, especially given that there are now multiple flavours of the runtime: "SDK", "ASP.Net Core runtime", ".Net Desktop Runtime", ".Net Runtime" ([see here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0))?

All PCs are Win10 with no plans to start using Win11.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install *any* .NET 6 Runtime version. Except for critical bug fixes, breaking changes do not happen on the same major version. For your application, the .NET 6 Desktop Runtime is appropriate.

Yes, .NET (Core) updates are distributed using Windows Update. For example, I received this recent update: [KB5017915](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-net-6-0-update-september-13-2022-kb5017915-c76c2daf-4d18-4003-bb2f-7e6846d8654f)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to net6autoupdate.reg and run it

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NET\6.0]
"AllowAUOnServerOS"=dword:00000001
```

Source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/server-operating-systems-auto-updates/

Comment: Link only answer is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a litle more?

Comment: Since my many systems (Windows Server 2016, 2019) won't get any .net core updates from Windows Update I was searching for a solution. And it came from Microsoft itself.


You have to add those keys to the registry. Right after that I run Windows Update and got 6.0.9 as an update for the already installed 6.0.8.

So as you can see that was not 'Link only reply'.

Comment: I'm guessing that this works only on Windows Server...?